# MongoDB works only on user is assigned to admin database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-4.0

I am using mongo db with authentication and it is working as expected when I map the user to the admin database like below,

```
use admin;
db.getUsers();
    {
                    "_id" : "admin.test1",
                    "userId" : UUID("abee0e0c-1d0b-44fa-84ad-594159b66aab"),
                    "user" : "test1",
                    "db" : "admin",
                    "roles" : [
                            {
                                    "role" : "readWrite",
                                    "db" : "test_database"
                            }
                    ],
                    "mechanisms" : [
                            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                    ]
            }
```

I am able to connect to the database using '`test1`' user and access the '`test_database`'

but when I create user with actual `test_database`, It is not allowing me to connect,

```
use test_database;
db.getUsers();
     {
                        "_id" : "test_database.test2",
                        "userId" : UUID("abee0e0c-1d0b-44fa-84ad-594159b66aab"),
                        "user" : "test2",
                        "db" : "test_database",
                        "roles" : [
                                {
                                        "role" : "readWrite",
                                        "db" : "test_database"
                                }
                        ],
                        "mechanisms" : [
                                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                        ]
                }
```

When I connect using the '`test1`' user to connect 'test_database', I am able to connect and It is working as expected (weird how the admin database access helps 'test_database' though) - why?

but when I connect using the user '`test2`' it fails with the following error

**pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.**

Comment: How do you connect? Usually in connection string you specify the authentication database (which defaults to "admin")

Comment: Actually I don't know any reason to create users anywhere apart from the `admin` database. The only situation I can imagine is when you like to provide users some kind of "mongo playground" where they can use their dedicated database as they like.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, adding the auth_source in the client connection solved the issue

Comment: Thanks for your time @WernfriedDomscheit